# Multiple handler entries in lsnrctl services output

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

This what I get for an `lsnrctl services`.

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 04-APR-2014 10:01:43

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "ORACLE SERVER" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:25 state:ready
         CLRExtProc
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\NTN_2088_83FB68BD.ORA))
      "ORACLE SERVER" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:25 state:ready
         CLRExtProc
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\NTN_2088_83FB68BD.ORA))
The command completed successfully
```

It seems there are 2, but equal "Handler" entries in the output. What is this? Isn't it an oracle bug?

Comment: Wonderful! I've got a Tumbleweed badge for this question! :-)